# Errors while using sstream in android

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-source

I'm writing an executable for android, and in it I use `std::stringstream`.
Therefore, I include the library `<sstream>`, and when I compile my code, I get the following linker errors:

```
external/libcxx/include/streambuf:220: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::locale::~locale()'
external/libcxx/include/ios:661: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::~ios_base()'
external/libcxx/include/ios:524: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
external/libcxx/include/ostream:260: error: undefined reference to 'std::uncaught_exception()'
external/libcxx/include/ios:524: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
external/libcxx/include/ios:524: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
external/libcxx/include/istream:291: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const'
external/libcxx/include/__locale:186: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const'
external/libcxx/include/istream:291: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::locale::~locale()'
external/libcxx/include/ios:524: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)'
external/libcxx/include/istream:304: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ctype<char>::id'
external/libcxx/include/ios:668: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::ios_base::init(void*)'
external/libcxx/include/streambuf:370: error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::locale::locale()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what I did wrong.. all the other STL classes worked fine until now.

Here is the project's Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -w

LOCAL_MODULE := my_module

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
     $(LOCAL_PATH)/includes

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng debug optional

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -static

LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    file_a.c \
    file_b.c \
    file_c.c

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    file_1.cpp \
    file_2.cpp \
    file_3.cpp

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
    liblog \
    libc

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_SBIN)

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you link using `gcc` or `g++`? Does the standard library on Android include the stream classes? To check you'd need to find the linked `libstdc++` and use the corresponding `nm` to find if the missing symbols are defined.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, I'm using the AOSP build. I've added a new executable under `/system/extras/` and I posted my Android makefile that I use to build my program.